# How do I increment an individual element in an Array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, element

I keep receiving the error

> Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type '[Int]' when trying to increment an individual element in array by 1

```
import Foundation
func aVeryBigSum(ar: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    
    var arA = [0,0]
    
    if ar[0] < ar[1]
    {
       arA = ar[0] + 1
    }
    else if ar [0] > ar[1]{
       arA = ar[1] + 1
    }
    return arA
}

print(aVeryBigSum(ar: [5,2]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is what Xcode tries to tell you, that you are trying to assign an `Int` to an `[Int]` array. You are doing that here:

```
 arA = ar[0] + 1
```

and here:

```
arA = ar[1] + 1
```

To improv your code you need to access the element in your `[Int]` array you want to update, for instance:

```
arA[0] = ar[0] + 1
// And
arA[0] = ar[1] + 1
```